# How can DDPG handle the discrete action space?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, ddpg

I am wondering how can DDPG or DPG handle the discrete action space. There are some papers saying that use Gumbel softmax with DDPG can make the discrete action problem be solved. However, will the Gumbel softmax make the deterministic policy be the stochastic one? If not, how can that be achieved?